# changing the text inside a div depend upon jquery toggleState

Tags: jquery, text, toggle, slidetoggle

I am creating a drop down menu. On clicking the parent element i want to change a text of a div.

```
 <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="superlative.php?page=home"id="home">home</a></li>
            <li>
                 <a href="#">about<div id="cont"></div></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.php" id="about">my story</a></li>
                        <li><a href="thefarmers.php" id="about">the farmers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="brunes.php" id="about">BRUNEUS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php" id="about">Health Benefits</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="nut_cluster.php?page=products" id="products">products</a></li>`
```

and script is

```
$(function(){

$("#nav ul li:has(ul)").click(function()
    {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        if($(this).children('ul').is(':hidden'))
        {
            $(this).find('#cont').text("+");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).find('#cont').text("-");
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is with the detection of toggle state. why it is always "-" when clicked on li. how can i fix it to show, text of #cont, as + when its ul is not visible, and - when its ul is visible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced similar issue before.

I don't know the exact reasoning behind the fact that after `slideToggle()` is invoked , element hidden state check always returns `false`.

So the workaround will be to check the state before `slideToggle()` is called.

```
$(function(){

    $("#nav ul li:has(ul)").click(function()
        {
            var toggleState= $(this).children('ul').is(':hidden');
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
            if(!toggleState)
            {
                $(this).find('#cont').text("+");
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).find('#cont').text("-");
            }
        });
    });
```

And here is the working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfM2K/).

Answer (score 1):

Look this solution, can make it easy for you if you have many open-closed `<ul>'s` and its easier for you set a style for your plus-minus symbol:

CSS:

```
#nav ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#nav ul li a.parent:after { /*this will append one pseudo-after to your a.parent*/
    content:attr(open-closed); /*this will take the attribute open-closed="" as content*/
    display:block;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:10px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    background:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#nav ul li:has(ul) > a').addClass('parent').on('click',function(e){ //it will add a class parent to each a that has siblings ul
    e.preventDefault(); // it will disable a.parent href on click
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('',function(){
        checkOpenClosed(); // it will execute the checkOpenClosed function after slideToggle finish
    });
});

function checkOpenClosed() {
    $('a.parent').each(function(){
        if($(this).siblings('ul').is(':visible')){
            $(this).attr('open-closed','−'); // if the siblings ul is visible the value is '-'
        } else {
            $(this).attr('open-closed','+'); // else, the value is '+'
        }
    });
}
checkOpenClosed();
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/qMXNZ/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by the selector `$(this).children('ul').is(':hidden')`, try to check visibility this way `$(this).children('ul').css('display') == 'none'`

Answer (score 0):

Because anchor tag default css "**text-decoration: underline;**".

You have to set css

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;    
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rfM2K/1/)**